# VirtualBox: Guest Addition for Mac OSX guest in Windows host?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, virtualbox, guest-additions

I have Windows 7 host, and Mac OS X installed as a guest with VirtualBox. How can I install the Guest Additions? Do they exist for Mac OS X guest?

Comment: You do know that this is illegal, right ?

Comment: You can get things like clipboard sync and shared folders working yourself by using VNC and SMB. Here's more detailed instructions how to do that: https://blog.tomtasche.at/2017/04/setting-up-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox.html

Answer (score 1):

As the MacOS X User License states that the operational system cannot be installed on any non-apple hardware, the official tools cannot be made available by publishers of any virtualization environment.

That being said, there are (illegal) versions of installers and images of virtual machines for MacOS, but they run slow as hell (even if you have awesome hardware) and, to my knowledge there are no "unnofficial" tools that can be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OSX is not officially supported as a guest OS and therefore no guest additions version officially exists. You may try to coerce a Linux version of GA, but it'd be iffy at best.